# What are the statements called in a Java class?

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
public class Temp {
   public boolean foo(int x) {
      if(x == 3956681)
        return true;
      else if(x == 9855021)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
   }
}
```

I am writing a report and I am a bit confused about what the statements are called for the following code:

```
Temp tempClass0 = new Temp();
int int2 = 99;
boolean boolean0 = tempClass0.foo(int2);
```

The first statement is called `creating an object` statement.

The second statement is called `defining a variable` statement.

The third statement is called `calling a method` statement.

I am not quite sure about each of them. Can you please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as a statement being "called" something. The first statement here has a variable declaration, a class creation expression and an assignment (kinda - it's not really an assignment, but rather an initializer, as part of the variable declaration).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5

Comment: 1) a `Temp` variable declaration initialized to the result of the default, no argument constructor 2) an `int` variable declaration initialized to a primitive integer 3) a `boolean` variable declaration initialized to the result of a method call

Answer (score 1):

There are a few statements with `=` operator:

**Initialization** is assignment starting value for your variable:

```
Temp tempClass0 = new Temp();
```

**Assignment** is just changing old value of variable to new one:

```
tempClass0 = new Temp();
```

**Defining(declaration)** is just declaration of variable type and name:

```
Temp tempClass0;
```

What about

> The first statement is called creating an object statement.

Everywhere you see `new` operator it is creating a new object.
In first example the `tempClass0` variable is initialized by new object.

**Update**

you might find it useful: [about 'dot' operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html), [declaring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), [initializing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), [creating object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score -1):

1. First statement is initialization
2. Second statement is declaration + initialization of variable
3. Third statement is assignment (here you are assigning value to your boolean0 variable)

Comment: The three of them declare and initialize a variable. Which involves assigning a value to that variable.